# how to make CommunityBuilder search functions not case sensitive

Tags: joomla

especially joomla users and experts...

for anyone who using Community Builder, how do you disable the case sensitive for the search function? i want it to be wildcard

Answer (score 0):

I've never looked at the CB code, but I would believe that you need to change the sql string that is used for the search.

So if the sql query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM #__cb WHERE title LIKE '%$search_term%'
```

Then you should do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM #__cb WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('%$search_term%')
```

OR

```
$search_term = strtolower($search_term);
SELECT * FROM #__cb WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%$search_term%'
```